# How to properly set up CircleCI plugin

Tags: spring-boot, circleci

I am trying to integrate CircleCI plugin with my spring-pet-clinic  project. I was following the instruction on CircleCI web page. I have created `.circleci` folder inside my project root folder.

Inside `.circleci` I have added config.yml file and copy-pasted config    from CircleCI page

My config was like this:

```
# Use the latest 2.1 version of CircleCI pipeline processing engine, 
see https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/
version: 2.1

# Use a package of configuration called an orb, see 
https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/orb-intro/
orbs:
  # Declare a dependency on the welcome-orb
  welcome: circleci/welcome-orb@0.3.1

# Orchestrate or schedule a set of jobs, see 
https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/
workflows:
  # Name the workflow "Welcome"
  Welcome:
    # Run the welcome/run job in its own container
    jobs:
      - welcome/run
```

After I ran the project CircleCI has thrown an error. Especially this one: "Config Processing Error: Don't rerun"

```
 $#!/bin/sh -eo pipefail
        # No configuration was found in your project. Please refer to 
        https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/ to get started with your 
        configuration.
        # 
        # -------
        # Warning: This configuration was auto-generated to show you 
        the 
        message above.
        # Don't rerun this job. Rerunning will have no effect.
        false
        Exited with code 1
```

Spin Up Environment looks like this

```
        Build-agent version 1.0.10572-3ce00c85 (2019-04- 
        15T22:09:28+0000)
        Docker Engine Version: 17.05.0-ce
        Kernel Version: Linux b0a81c56acff 4.4.0-144-generic 
        #170~14.04.1- 
        Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 18 15:02:05 UTC 2019 x86_64 Linux
        Starting container bash:4.4.19
          using image 
 bash@sha256:9f0a4aa3c9931bd5fdda51b1b2b74a0398a8eabeaf9519d807e010b9d9d41993

        Using build environment variables
          BASH_ENV=/tmp/.bash_env-5cbebf83d4b030000849b60f-0-build
          CI=true
          CIRCLECI=true
          CIRCLE_BRANCH=master
          CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM=5
          CIRCLE_BUILD_URL=https://circleci.com/gh/sajmon2325/Spring- 
          Pet- 
          Clinic/5
          CIRCLE_COMPARE_URL=
          CIRCLE_JOB=Build Error
          CIRCLE_NODE_INDEX=0
          CIRCLE_NODE_TOTAL=1
          CIRCLE_PREVIOUS_BUILD_NUM=4
          CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME=Spring-Pet-Clinic
          CIRCLE_PROJECT_USERNAME=sajmon2325
          CIRCLE_REPOSITORY_URL=git@github.com:sajmon2325/Spring-Pet- 
          Clinic.git
          CIRCLE_SHA1=48f6db114b41c338e606de32d8648c64ba5119fd
          CIRCLE_SHELL_ENV=/tmp/.bash_env-5cbebf83d4b030000849b60f-0- 
              build
          CIRCLE_STAGE=Build Error
          CIRCLE_USERNAME=sajmon2325
          CIRCLE_WORKFLOW_ID=2789d93e-f1e4-4c81-93f1-846f7d38c107
          CIRCLE_WORKFLOW_JOB_ID=670105ca-617e-445e-9b5e-6ac57f6af8da
          CIRCLE_WORKFLOW_UPSTREAM_JOB_IDS=
          CIRCLE_WORKFLOW_WORKSPACE_ID=2789d93e-f1e4-4c81-93f1- 
          846f7d38c107
          CIRCLE_WORKING_DIRECTORY=~/project

          Using environment variables from project settings and/or 
          contexts
          CIRCLE_JOB=**REDACTED**
```

So at first I thought that I have only a skeleton of CircleCI configuration, that's why I have edited my config.yml file to look like this (the actual version)

```
 # Java Maven CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
    #
    # Check https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-java/ for more details
    #
    version: 2
    jobs:
        build:
            docker:
            # specify the version you desire here
            - image: circleci/openjdk:11-browsers-legacy

            # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
            # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
            # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
            # - image: circleci/postgres:9.4

            working_directory: ~/repo

            environment:
                # Customize the JVM maximum heap limit
                MAVEN_OPTS: -Xmx3200m

            steps:
            - checkout

            # Download and cache dependencies
            - restore_cache:
                  keys:
                  - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "pom.xml" }}
                  # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match 
                is 
            found
                  - v1-dependencies-

            - run: mvn install -DskipTests

            - run: mvn dependency:go-offline

            - save_cache:
                  paths:
                  - ~/.m2
                  key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "pom.xml" }}

            # run tests!
            - run: mvn integration-test
```

But even this is not working. I still have the same error:

```
$#!/bin/sh -eo pipefail
# No configuration was found in your project. Please refer to https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/ to get started with your configuration.
# 
# -------
# Warning: This configuration was auto-generated to show you the message above.
# Don't rerun this job. Rerunning will have no effect.
false
Exited with code 1
```

I just need to successfully integrate CircleCi plugin with my project. If you need to see my repo, here is the link: https://github.com/sajmon2325/Spring-Pet-Clinic.git

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `.circleci` is not in the root of the repository. It is currently in `sfg-pet-clinic/`, and the CircleCI build process won't find it there.